# What are all the holes on an engine block deck surface?

Tags: engine

I want to know what are all the holes for on a engine block deck surface? I Know some are to help with putting the cylinder head on and others are to bolt the head down. But what are the rest?

Comment: A picture would work wonders here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other holes are to allow coolant and/or oil to flow through the cylinder head and engine block.

The coolant is needed to help cool down the combustion chamber.

Here is an example of a Chrysler engine block with coolant holes.

[image: Chrysler Block]
<sub>(source: [440source.com](http://www.440source.com/deck1.jpg))</sub>

On overhead cam engines the camshafts require oil for lubricating the journal bearings that they spin on.

Comment: That's what I thought. Have a head gaskets that's fits my block but covers those holes a bit. Someone told me it was okay but I knee better. Will any gasket made by Ford for L4 Engine work for every ford L4 Engine or do models have differences

Comment: @LostPecti that doesn't sound right. Your gasket should have provision for those holes.

Comment: Maybe I put it on wrong. Its not coving up to much but still it should be exact.

Comment: @LostPecti post up some pictures in your gasket question. That will eliminate guesswork from other users who would like to help.

Comment: @LostPecti If you place the gasket over the cover in the right position, and you are sure it is there, but still some holes are covering, check if you can open or expand the holes **a bit** with a piercing tool. Holes needs to be all open for gaskets and ideally perfect match.